# Unable to remove "top answer" from the list

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am trying to remove the following "top answer" from my CV:

[image]

There are at least three problems here:

- the "14 votes" text is overlaying the up and down arrows
- the "remove" link is very difficult to click
- the "remove" link doesn't work

When I click the link, I receive a `confirm()` dialog asking if I'm sure. I click "OK" and absolutely nothing happens. Refreshing the page confirms that nothing happened.

**Browser:** Opera 32.0.1948.69 on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remove button should work now and the css should be a smidge better but there are some other problems with move up/down I need to dig into.